# Java for loop not stopping. what is wrong with the code

Tags: java, for-loop, processing

It seems like the for loop in my code is not stopping after it iterated througt the counter. it seems to restart, checked with the print function and the length of the directory list seems to be recognized but then it restarts from 0 and so on. First time coding with java and in general i do not have much experience in coding, logic experience comes from visual coding and little bit of python. if somebody can help it would be great.

here is the code,
to run it you need will need processing (https://processing.org/download) and some images in the input folder. thougth this is an easy problem, thats why i still post it here.

I know its not pretty so pls dont hate on it

```
int dim = 1024;
PImage img;
String inDir;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

String outDir;
String nameSpace;
String nameSpaceOut; 
PGraphics pg;

void setup() {
  size(1024, 1024);
  inDir = "C:/Users/Fynn/Desktop/processing-3.5.4/Resizematte/data/Input 1/";
  outDir = "C:/Users/Fynn/Desktop/processing-3.5.4/Resizematte/data/Output 3/";
  nameSpace = "ImageToResize";
  pg = createGraphics(dim, dim);

  nameSpaceOut = "Resized";
}

void draw () {
  background(0);

  pg.beginDraw();

  File dir = new File(inDir);
  String[] filenames = dir.list();

  for (int i = 0; i < filenames.length; i++) {
    background(255, 255, 255);
    String fName = inDir + filenames[i];

    img = loadImage(fName);
    if (img != null) {
      float w = img.width;
      float h = img.height;
      float m = w;
      float f = h;
      if (h > w) { //change to < for crop > for matte
        m = h;
        f = w;
      }
      float factor = (dim/m);
      if(h > w){
        img.resize(int(f*factor), int(m*factor));
      }
      else {
       img.resize(int(m*factor), int(f*factor));
      }

      image(img, width/2-img.width/2, height/2-img.height/2);
      String outName1 = outDir + nameSpaceOut + "_" + i +".png";
     save(outName1);
     }
   }
}
```

i try to format pictures which i want to use as a data set input for a GAN machine learnign algorithm.

Comment: Because `draw()` is being repeatedly called, perhaps?

Comment: from the [Processing Overview](https://processing.org/tutorials/overview) tutorial: "*The setup() block runs once, and the draw() block runs repeatedly.*" (reading tutorials is *lame*, I know... :-/ )